# summit hokuyo data

Tags: ros, gazebo, laser, gazebo-plugin, hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Robotnik,

I have some question about sensor hokuyo and the data received.

I have some troubles to use the stack summit_sim in FUERTE.

I rosmaked summit_description, summit_controller inside this stack and launch the description robot:

$ roslaunch summit_description summit.launch

It looks great but in the verbose of gazebo server I have this warning:

```
...
...
Dbg skipping prefixed element [interface:audio] when copying plugins
Dbg skipping prefixed element [interface:audio] when copying plugins
Dbg skipping prefixed element [interface:position] when copying plugins
spawn status:  SpawnModel: successfully spawned model
Dbg plugin parent sensor name: hokuyo_laser
[ WARN] [1338277432.923449936]: Laser plugin missing <hokuyoMinIntensity>, defaults to 101
[ INFO] [1338277432.923541873]: INFO: gazebo_ros_laser plugin should set minimum intensity to 101.000000 due to cutoff in hokuyo filters.
Error [Plugin.hh:100] Failed to load plugin libgazebo_ros_time.so: libgazebo_ros_time.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Dbg plugin model name: summit
[ INFO] [1338277432.931752412]: starting gazebo_ros_controller_manager plugin in ns: /
[ INFO] [1338277432.931997347]: Callback thread id=0x7f7bc00cedf0
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
[spawn_object-6] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/pablo/.ros/log/07bdad80-a962-11e1-ac58-5404a64baafd/spawn_object-6*.log
[ WARN] [1338277433.242845571]: imu plugin missing <serviceName>, defaults to /default_imu
[ WARN] [1338277433.242977926]: imu plugin missing <xyzOffset>, defaults to 0s
[ WARN] [1338277433.243170950]: imu plugin missing <rpyOffset>, defaults to 0s
[ INFO] [1338277433.328125825, 0.022000000]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
[ INFO] [1338277433.364027285, 0.058000000]: Starting to spin physics dynamic reconfigure node...
[INFO] [WallTime: 1338277433.501923] [0.195000] Loaded controllers: summit_controller
[INFO] [WallTime: 1338277433.505892] [0.199000] Started controllers: summit_controller
```

Ok this is very weird because I can launch other worlds without troubles. I don't know why but I can't see the fan laser rays in the world. I can get the information of the hokuyo sensor (very bad data because it isn't logic data --> I receive only values between 0.25 and 0.05, it looks like the sensor are inside the chassis of the robot.).

If help, I put the code here:

```
<!-- HOKUYO SENSOR -->

  <joint name="hokuyo_laser_joint" type="fixed">
     <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
     <origin xyz="0.226 0 0.125"/> 
     <!-- origin xyz="0.226 0 0.126"/ -->
     <parent link="base_link"/>
     <child link="hokuyo_laser_link"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="hokuyo_laser_link" type="laser">
     <inertial>
       <mass value="0.001" />
       <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
       <inertia ixx="0.0001" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.000001" iyz="0" izz="0.0001" />
    </inertial>
  </link>

  <!-- This adds a visual box to allow us to see the Hokuyo in rviz/gazebo -->
  <joint name="hokuyo_laser_box_joint" type="fixed">
    <origin xyz="0 0 -0.02" rpy="0 0 0" /> <!-- sensor hokuyo down 2 cm -->
    <parent link="hokuyo_laser_link" />
    <child link="hokuyo_laser_box_link"/>
  </joint>
  <link name="hokuyo_laser_box_link">
    <inertial>
      <mass value="0.01" />
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" />
      <inertia ixx="0.001"  ixy="0.0"  ixz="0.0"
               iyy="0.001"  iyz="0.0"
               izz="0.001" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <!--box size="0.05 0.05 0.1" /-->
    <mesh filename= "package://pr2_description/meshes/tilting_laser_v0/hok_tilt.stl" scale="0.5 0.5 0.5"/>
      </geometry>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.05 0.05 0.1" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>

  <gazebo reference="hokuyo_laser_box_link">
    <material>Gazebo/Blue</material> <!-- missing magenta color in Gazebo.materials -->
    <turnGravityOff>false</turnGravityOff>
  </gazebo>

  <!-- Other controllers (HOKUYO SENSOR) -->

  <gazebo reference = "hokuyo_laser_link">
    <sensor:ray name="hokuyo_laser">
       <rayCount>640</rayCount>
       <rangeCount>640</rangeCount>
       <laserCount>1</laserCount>

       <origin>0.0 0.0 0.0</origin>
       <!--<displayRays>fan</displayRays>-->

       <minAngle>-120</minAngle>
       <maxAngle>120</maxAngle>
    
       <minRange>0.05</minRange>
       <maxRange>4.0</maxRange>
       <resRange>0.001</resRange>
       <updateRate>10.0</updateRate>
       <controller:gazebo_ros_laser name="gazebo_ros_hokuyo_laser_controller" plugin="libgazebo_ros_laser.so">
         <gaussianNoise>0.005</gaussianNoise>
         <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
         <updateRate>10.0</updateRate>
         <topicName>hokuyo_laser_topic</topicName>
         <frameName>hokuyo_laser_link</frameName>
         <interface:laser name="gazebo_ros_hokuyo_laser_iface" />
       </controller:gazebo_ros_laser>
    </sensor:ray>
   </gazebo>
```

I know this is a mixed formats (old deprecated format + new gazebo 1.0.1 format) but this stack is close enaugh to work in FUERTE (I can teleoperate with the keyboard and subscribe to hokuyo_laser_topic with my own node)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35128/summit-hokuyo-data/) by [pmarinplaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1959/pmarinplaza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2012-05-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

yes, you just need to modify the height of the laser link

****

---

Originally posted by [Robotnik](https://answers.ros.org/users/1119/robotnik/) with karma: 71 on 2012-11-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0